# How can be unique each row in sqlite table. Not just a column of row

Tags: android, sqlite, unique

I have a sqlite table with two column like name and surname .I want name and surname must be different not just name.

My table code is

```js
private static final String MAKE_TABLE_NAME_SURNAME = "CREATE TABLE " +
 TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM + "(" + KEY_DSID  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
 NAME + " TEXT, " + SURNAME + " TEXT) ";
```

I can't use

```java
private static final String MAKE_TABLE_NAME_SURNAME = "CREATE TABLE " +
 TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM + "(" + KEY_DSID  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
 NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE, " + SURNAME + " TEXT UNIQUE) ";
```

Because if I use this code then I can't add same name but different Surname or same Surname but different name. How can ignore if only both of them is same.

Comment: You can make both `NAME` and `SURNAME` the primary key of your table: `"CREATE TABLE " +
 TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM + "(" + NAME + " " + SURNAME + " PRIMARY KEY (" + NAME + ", " + SURNAME + ")) "` , but I am not sure if this is a really good idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following is what you want :-

```
private static final String MAKE_TABLE_NAME_SURNAME = "CREATE TABLE " +
   TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM + "(" + KEY_DSID  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
   NAME + " TEXT, " + SURNAME + " TEXT, UNIQUE(" + NAME + "," + SURNAME +")) ";
```

That is you are defining a combination of the name column and the surname columns as the UNIQUE constraint.

For example consider :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM (KEY_DSID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, UNIQUE(NAME,SURNAME));
INSERT INTO TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM (NAME,SURNAME) VALUES('Fred','Bloggs'),('Fred','Smith'),('Mary','Smith'),('Jane','Doe');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM (NAME,SURNAME) VALUES('Fred','Bloggs'); -- will not be inserted as duplicate
SELECT * FROM TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM;
```

The first 4 inserts work, the last (on it's own) is ignored (as it's a duplicate).
Thus the final query produces :-

[image]

The log is :-

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM (NAME,SURNAME) VALUES('Fred','Bloggs'),('Fred','Smith'),('Mary','Smith'),('Jane','Doe')
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.117s


INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TABLE_DISEASE_SEMPTOM (NAME,SURNAME) VALUES('Fred','Bloggs')
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0.117s
```

i.e. the last insert inserted no rows

Comment: Thank you,This is answer which is I search.

Answer (score 1):

This check is done on the server/app side.
(check your variables before trying to insert them into your database)

Comment: Thank you,I also used this answer.